# Serializing protobuf from skynet and Serializing in C# gives different bytes

Tags: c#, lua, protocol-buffers

I am not responsible nor familiar with Skynet, but I am sure it uses Protobuf version 3.14.0, and it should use the c language version.
I am responsible for the C#(unity3d) side, Protobuf version 3.14.0, downloaded from Nuget.
Here is part of .proto：

```
 syntax = "proto3";
    ...
message tookPoint {
    points point = 1;
    int32 mid = 2;
    int32 capital = 3; 
}
message points {
    int32 offset = 1; 
    repeated int32 color = 2; 
    int32 flag = 3;
}
```

When I send
`{ "point": { "offset": 5097, "color": [ 7 ], "flag": 1 }, "mid": 1, "capital": 1 }`
to server,it log
`{point={offset=5097, flag=1, color={5}}, mid=1, capital=1}`

I have search about the answer about C++ and lua,but they are useless to solve the problem.I need more help T T.I have cost more than 3 days on it.

How can I send the right bytes to server T T ?Thanks you~~

---

For debug.`{point={offset=2204, flag=1, color={8}}, mid=1, capital=1}`,server reuslt is `10 01 18 10 0A 07 10 08 08 9c 11 18 01`.C# result is `0A 08 08 9C 11 12 01 08 18 01 10 01 18 10`.Both of them can deserialize correctly in C#.

---

protobuf Version in Skynet is libprotoc 3.14.0

Comment: Protobuf can represent the same data in multiple ways - at the most basic level: by different field order, which is very possible given the "10 01 18 10" that moves in the example - but in other ways too. Unfortunately, the tool that I usually use to investigate this is offline at the moment while I fix a broken Azure subscription problem (https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode). I'm kinda doing the "weekend" thing, but if you're still stuck by Monday and no solution has arrived, I can almost certainly help then (when I'm at a computer).

Comment: What you mean seems to mean that protobuf has certain functions to ensure that it is serialized into the same byte string under different platforms?

Comment: no, I mean the very opposite; I mean there is no single correct set of bytes on any platform - there are, however, some *conventions* that are often, but not always, followed - which means the output often looks the same

Comment: Well, I accept the reality of different bytecodes of data on different platforms. Now I want to know about the sample protocol, is the result of deserialization on your platform Color=5 or Color=7? Is there any way I can ensure that the client and server are consistent? Many thanks@@

Comment: Still on my list to look at on Monday; not ignoring you - just: weekending

Comment: I got the tool working, yay! So; you can see the decoded value by putting the hex in here:  https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode; the main difference, as discussed, is the field order - one version is using 1/2/3, the other is using 2/3/1; both are valid. As for the values; that's more interesting; `int32` is encoded as a varint, which for values < 128 means the value is encoded directly as-is; are you saying that one of them is not doing this, and is corrupting the values?

Comment: This is really useful! Both segments of hex can be correctly restored to ‘{point={offset=2204, flag=1, color={8}}’, mid=1, capital=1} on the website! The problem seems to be on the server. The strange thing is that no one has ever mentioned an issue. I will continue to track the specific details of the bug, it seems that it is not only related to protobuf

Comment: @MarcGravell I have found the cause and solution of the problem.Tk a lot >.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause and solution of the problem. Protobuf's C# class library defaults that repeat objects are all packed, and libprotoc 3.14.0 still decodes according to the previous encoding scheme before it is configured. As a result, libprotoc 3.14.0 cannot decode the correct result. The solution is to configure libprotoc 3.14.